# How to run terminal command in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, terminal, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to test out running terminal commands through a macOS app. The command I am trying to run is "mkdir ~/Desktop/test" on a button click, but I think what I have so far is too simple to actually work. Or maybe it's a limitation of xCode not allowing access to my Desktop folder from the simulator?

Below is the code I have. 
The shell function is simply just a copy-paste of an answer I found here on StackOverflow:

```
struct ContentView: View {  

@discardableResult func shell(_ command: String) -> (String?, Int32) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return (output, task.terminationStatus)
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Button(action: {
        self.shell("mkdir ~/Desktop/test")
      }) {
        Text("Run Command").font(.body)
      }      
   }.frame(width:500,height:500)    }

}
```

My ultimate goal is to try and run the screenshot command "cd ~/Desktop/ | screencapture  test101.jpg". So if it's possible, would also love to know if i could pop this command into the shell function and also have it run.